# Show div onclick function using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am new in web development. I am trying to show div onclick function so I need some help.

here is my code

```
<div id="editdiv<?php echo $consultnt->id?>" style="display:none">
                        <p>  edit</p>
                          </div>
                          <?php if(trim($consultnt->status) !="completed"){ ?>
                           <div class="pull-right" id="div_chng_hr">
                                         <input type="submit" name="edit_hour" onClick="showEdit(<?php echo "editdiv".$consultnt->id ?>)" on value="Edit Hour">
                                         </div>
                                         <?php  } ?>
```

and script code here is

```
function showEdit(id){
        $('#editdiv').show();
        }
```

I inspect edit hour button then I have value onclick

```
<input type="submit" name="edit_hour" onclick="showEdit(editdiv26)"  value="Edit Hour">
```

and div id is

```
<div id="editdiv26" style="display:none">
```

tell me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: use `$('#' + id)` instead of `$('#editdiv')`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are giving the function a param

```
onClick="showEdit(<?php echo " 'editdiv".$consultnt->id." ' "?>)"
```

eter it shoud be between ' '
So the onClick function should be

And in your function use "#" + id instead of #editdiv

Answer (score 0):

```
function showEdit(id){
   $('#editdiv' + id).show();
}
```

Your div have different id that "editdiv" because it's extended by consultant id. So you have to use consultant id in your function as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Concat the ID properly. Since you have a static `editdiv` and a dynamic ID use `$('#editdiv' + id)`

```js
function showEdit(id) {
  $('#editdiv' + id).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editdiv1" style="display:none">1 </div>
<div class="pull-right" id="div_chng_hr">
  <input type="button" name="edit_hour" onClick="showEdit(1)" on value="Edit Hour">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing is make sure you link a jQuery library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

second thing is code

```
<div id="editdiv<?php echo $consultnt->id?>" style="display:none">
    <p>  edit</p>
</div>
<?php if(trim($consultnt->status)!='completed'){ ?>
    <div class="pull-right" id="div_chng_hr">
        <input type="submit" name="edit_hour" onClick="showEdit(<?php echo $consultnt->id?>)" on value="Edit Hour">
    </div>
 <?php  } ?>
<script>
    function showEdit(id){
        $('#editdiv'+id).show();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Use this html: remove 'editdiv' text from onClick event**
>
> ```
> <div id="editdiv<?php echo $consultnt->id?>" style="display:none">
>   <p>  edit</p>
> </div>
> <?php if(trim($consultnt->status) !="completed"){ ?>
>   <div class="pull-right" id="div_chng_hr">
>       <input type="submit" name="edit_hour" onClick="showEdit(<?php echo $consultnt->id ?>)" on value="Edit Hour">
>   </div>
> <?php  } ?>
> ```
>
> script part:
>
> ```
> <script>
>   function showEdit(id){
>       $('#editdiv'+id).show();
>   }
>
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at here working example

```
    `https://jsfiddle.net/yhpduthm/10/`
```

I prefer in function you have to add only **ID** and that will use in function.